# ThreadPoolExecutor for running AbortableHttpRequest - how to call abort?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, http, threadpool

I'm running a networking service in android where I direct all my http requests to run and get callbacks from the service when the requests are complete. I run the requests in a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) to limit the number of concurrent requests. As the requests run within the pool, they eventually create an HttpGet or HttpPost, both of which indirectly implement [AbortableHttpRequest](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/AbortableHttpRequest.html), which allows one to cancel the connection (say, if it's blocking for a long time).

If a user cancels a request, I'd like to somehow drill into the thread queue and call the abort routine for that request. If, for example, a web site is not responding and the user chooses to do something else, right now my only option is to wait for the standard 5 minute http timeout to occur for that hung request before that thread is freed up. If I could access the thread that has my request and call abort, that would free things up right away.

From what I can understand, it appears once my request has gone into the thread pool, it's a black box until it comes out the other end. Querying the queue will only hand back futures, which hides the runnable.

Is there a better approach for this? I'm fairly new to java and threading (I mostly do perl, which doesn't do threads very well at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you give a task to a thread pool executor doesn't mean you can't hold a reference on it. Keep a reference on the task, and if the user chooses to cancel it, then call abort on your task.

```
public class MyAbortableRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private AbortableHttpRequest request;

    public void abort() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            if (request != null) {
                request.abort();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...
        // create the request
        synchronized(lock) {
            this.request = ...;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the shove in the right direction. I've been very immersed in threading the last couple of days, couldn't see the forest for the trees...